# Always show error picked up _JAVA_OPTION -Xmx512M in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

i migrate to eclipse to Android studio and install the latest version of Android studio 1.3 and i am using too many libraries projects and some of jar files. but now when i try to run this project its always show me

Picked up `_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M`

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

i place there he write hat remove `_JAVA_OPTION -Xm512` will remove app in you project but nothing happen. this is is below my gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iptikarpromotion"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:ImageSliderLibrary')
    compile project(':libraries:CircularImageView')
    compile project(':libraries:GalleryViewLibrary')
}
```

And manifist is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iptikarpromotion" >


    <permission
        android:name="com.example.iptikarpromotion.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

   <application android:name="com.iptikarpromotion.utils.ApplicationData"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBVgaZHjJmXd6pQNRISnzzSbEN0B3aJuns"/> <!-- bebug key=   AIzaSyBVgaZHjJmXd6pQNRISnzzSbEN0B3aJuns -->

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.LoaderActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.HomeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.DetailActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.WebviewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MapActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.GalleryViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MyFavourateActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MyAdsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.ContactUsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.OurServicesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.QuicklyPickActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.AllCategoriesGridViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.AllCategoriesChildActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.PromotionActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This my jar files

```
gson-2.1.jar
google-play-services.jar
google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar
AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0.jar.
```

Thanks

Comment: This may have nothing to do with you problem but you should bump the plugin version like so:

'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

Comment: Also bump the build tools version: buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

Comment: I get rid of last issue but now as you said i change the plugin version 1.2.3 also buildtoolversion 22.01 but now got this error                        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 4):

Remove Java_option in Environment Variable of System of Windows. Exit Android Studio and run it again.

Comment: after 10 days, I found the solution here. Thank You very Much.